# Vue: dynamic "v-slot = { value }" causes div to be hidden

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In Parent I included one ChildComponent as such:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <ChildComponent :value="var1" v-slot="{value}">
   <input v-model="value.name"/>
  </ChildComponent>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "../components/ChildComponent.vue";
export default {
 components: { ChildComponent },
 data() {
  return {
   var1: {
    name: "Vue.js",
    message: "LocalHost"
   }
  };
 }
</script>
```

ChildComponent:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div id="divToShow" v-if="this.$slots.default || this.$scopedSlots.value">
   <slot/>
  </div>
  <div v-else id="divFallback">
   <p>Nothing in your input component!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
 name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
   value: String
  }
 }
</script>
```

However, `divToShow` does not appear, so `divFallback` takes its place. How should I go about making `divToShow` show up when Parent defines a (seemingly) dynamic name slot like this?

Comment: scopedSlots uses functions to access the VNode, with the first argument for passing props. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots , try `this.$scopedSlots.value()`

Comment: **Do not** use `this` in templates

Comment: replacing `v-if="this.$slots.default || this.$scopedSlots.value"` with `v-if="$scopedSlots"` appears to have solved my problem, but I guess it's because I only used one scoped slot, or because I have defined a scoped slot so the value is not undefined/null.